# Block registration with viewScript

Tags: plugins, php, block-editor

I'm trying to include a frontend script for my block plugin that is registered via `block.json`. Below is what I have:

```
/
  plugin.php
  block.json
  scorecard.php
  scorecard.css
  scorecard.js
```

**plugin.php**

```php
add_action( 'init', 'sf_scorecard_block_init' );
function sf_scorecard_block_init() {
    register_block_type_from_metadata( __DIR__ );
}
```

**block.json**

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/block.json",
    "name": "sf/scorecard",
    "title": "Deal Scorecard",
    "description": "Display a scorecard for the selected Deal.",
    "viewScript": [ "file:./scorecard.js" ],
    "style": [ "file:./scorecard.css" ],
    "category": "embed",
    "textdomain": "sf",
    "icon": "yes-alt",
    "keywords": [ "scorecard", "deal" ],
    "acf": {
        "mode": "auto",
        "renderTemplate": "scorecard.php"
    },
    "align": "full"
}
```

**scorecard.js**

```js
console.log('loaded');
```

Everything with the block is working as expected (including the CSS file), but I cannot get the `scorecard.js` file to load and fire. I'm on WordPress 6.1, so `viewScript` should work [according to the docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-metadata/#view-script).

I'm also using this [block in conjunction with ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-blocks-with-block-json/), hence the `acf.renderTemplate` key. Not sure if that interferes with this or not...

Surely I'm missing something, but the documentation seems confusing on this topic. Most examples I see register the block via PHP and not `block.json`.

Comment: the use of ACF very likely interferes with it, have you confirmed this with a simple block that doesn't use ACF? And have you confirmed there are no PHP warnings or notices or errors in the JS console/network tab?

Comment: Yes, I have tried removing the `acf` portion and used the standard `render` key. The block still pulls in, but the JS does not. No console or network errors.